# How to go through an array of url and parse it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of URL's and I want to go to every page to parse some information. I do:

```
var numbers = ["1111", "2222", "3333"];

function parse(page){...
}

function set(page){
console.log(page);
window.location = page;
parse (page);
}

for (j=0,m = numbers.length; j<m; j++){
page="http://www.*****/*****/"+numbers[j]+"/*****/"; 
setInterval(set(page), 10000);
}
```

But it's not working because browser tries to download pages and at the end, only the last one will be displayed. Function "parse" does not parse pages. How to fix my code?

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` will call your `set` function once every 10 seconds the way you have invoked it. The `for` loop will have ended `before` that time, and the `page`'s value at that time will be:

```
"http://www.*****/*****/3333/*****/";
```

So after 10 seconds you will only see that page displayed.

Comment: Got it! Problem in for loop. There should be slowler than "set-parse". 
Is it possible to make a cycle slower?

Comment: You can specify any time interval you like but it wouldn't be a stable solution because you can never predict how much time each iteration will take.  A different solution is needed here

Answer (score 0):

Try use setTimeout combine with recursive call.

```
const MAX=100;
setPage(num){
parse()
if(num<MAX)
  setTimeout(setPage(num+1), 10000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help!

Comment: @ИльшатМурзурбеков, thank them by voting up their answer and marking it, or another, as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to Scopes and Closures in JS. The solution for the problem is to create IIFE(Immediately Invoked Function Expression) inside loop!

```js
for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
  page="http://www.*****/*****/"+numbers[j]+"/*****/"; 
    (function(j){
        setTimeout( set(page), 10000 );
    })( i );
}
```

If you have time, refer about Closures in JS!

Comment: I'm just beginner.Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

When you use `setInterval()`, you just tells the browser to carry out `set()` function after 10 seconds, and because all the `setInterval()` are been called in a very short period of time in that for loop, they will carry out the task together as well, then set will be carried out thrice, first with `"1111"` then `"2222"` and `"3333"`.
It would seems like it only run the last one with `"3333"`.
I suggest you use `setInterval()` only once, while the `page` variable will be created with a counter.

```
var counter=0
function count(){
    page="http://www.*****/*****/"+numbers[counter]+"/*****/";
    set(page);
    counter+=1;
    if(counter>=numbers.length){
        counter=0;
    }
}
setInterval(count(), 10000);
```

Comment: Is it normal, that chrome blocking my script "A parser-blocking, cross site script ...is invoked via document.write"

Comment: Did you tried to use document.write in another script file? It has some security issues I guess.

Comment: If it does not prevent your script from functioning, it's okay, but if it does, I guess you should put them in one file.

Comment: It's interesting because I haven't "document.write" in my code. 
And Chrome does not allow to go to another page. I dont know where is problem now. Maybe in parse function.
 https://pastebin.com/Jd3WqSdN

Comment: What do you mean when you write " you should put them in one file"? I put all my script into chrome console and wait for result

Comment: What I meant is that you said the error was "...cross site script...", so I guessed that you used some script hosted elsewhere.

Comment: Maybe you should download jquery and not using the cdn. It is wield though, because cdn does work on my site and many others.